# Extract interface implementation with Astah API

Tags: api, uml

I'm developing a parser for UML and I'm using Astah API to parse a .asta file.
I want to parse classes diagrams, but I can't figure out how to extract the interfaces that a class implements.

I've read the API doc which can be found here [API doc](http://members.change-vision.com/javadoc/astah-api/6_7_0-43495/api/en/doc/astahAPI_reference.html#sequence_diagram)

but all these getClientDependencies(),  getClientRealizations(), getSupplierDependencies(), getSupplierRealizations() don't work, they just return me an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, fellows,
The API doc provided was pretty correct. The UML diagram I was using to test was kinda wrong.

Thanks anyway